# How to manually verify CSRF token in Ajax request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf

I am building my first Laravel application and have a problem with the ajax request and specifically the CSRF verification.

I have followed all the steps in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf) but it is not exactly doing what is said in there.

> The App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group by default, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

I have been manually concatenating 'test' to all CSRF tokens from the meta tag and the responses is still going through which it shouldn't of course.

Do I now have to manually Verify the CSRF token? If not what's the best practice to verify a token send in the headers of a jquery ajax post request through the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what error that you encountered, but here's some Ajax setup and callin that i usually do.

```
//Setup header before callin ajax
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
//Ajax call update
$.ajax({
    url: '/posts/1/update',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: 123,
        content: 'Abc123',
    },
    complete: function (response, xhr, settings) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

You don't need to edit your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware to make this work.

Comment: I don't have an error. Quite the opposite actually. It doesn't matter what CSRF token I send the response still gets sent. I want to ONLY respond when the CSRF is verified but I am not sure what's the best way to implement the verification since there isn't one set up by default.